# Runtime system is sticky - Open server 5.0.5

Tags: upgrade, software-updates

When trying to install 5.0.6 update on a Open Server 5.0.5 system,  I get an error of "Run time System is sticky and the update fails to install.

I have used the command -
custom -v quick SCO:Unix:RTS -x
This does not correct  the problem.

Any ideas on what RTS is sticky means and how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I lot of looking and I found the problem.

Modify /etc/default/boot 
change
DEFBOOTSTR=hd(40)unix 
 to

DEFBOOTSTR=hd(40)unix swap=hd(41) dump=hd(41) root=hd(42)

The upgrade choice can now be used with the OS5.0.6 disk.